# What is the 'margin' attribute of Document in iText PDF for?

Tags: java, itext

What is `margin` attribute of Document e.g

```
Document(new Rectangle(PageSize.A4),8,2,75,0);
```

in which `8` means top margin in mm cm or pixel.

Answer (score 3):

PDF uses the *user unit* as measurement unit. One user unit roughly corresponds with a typographic point (1/72 of an inch).

The default user unit can be changed if a `/UserUnit` key is present. The default value (if the key is absent) is `1.0`. In this case, 1 user unit equals i.e. `1/72` of an inch.

According to the [Adobe Portable Document Format Reference version 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), p. 148, a `UserUnit` is defined as:

> A positive number giving the size of default user space units, in multiples of 1/72 inch. The range of supported values is implementation-dependent; see implementation note 177 in Appendix H. Default value: 1.0 (user unit is 1/72 inch).

So the value `8` means `8` points, i.e. `8/72` inches.

It is also good to note that (from p. 201):

> The default for the size of the unit in default user space (1/72 inch) is approximately the same as a *point*, a unit widely used in the printing industry. It is not exactly the same, however; there is no universal definition of a point.